# How to expose in different ports some of the NestJS application routes

Tags: routes, port, nestjs

I have a NestJS application that is served in one specific port, but I need to expose some of the routes (in example Prometheus metrics /metrics) with other port.

Is possible to do it within a NestJS application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, just instantiate the application modules separately. (I assume your application is organised in modules).

Here is a short example:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  // module with the selected endpoints
  const firstApp = await NestFactory.create(FirstAppModule);
  await firstApp.listen(3001);
  // module with different endpoints
  const secondApp = await NestFactory.create(SecondAppModule);
  await secondApp.listen(3002);
}
```

P.S. I don't recommend running multiple servers on the same Node process as it impacts the performance bad way, and also makes the monitoring, managing their lifecycle way harder. I suggest to use some process manager like [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) for that purpose.

Comment: The specific route was in the same main module, but I will extract it in order to make it available in a different port.